# Override tablesorter CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using jQuery tablesorter gem. When the page loads, I have a code to highlight the background color of certain rows in the table.

Since tablesorter is used I guess it overrides the css and not allowing to change the background color of the rows.

This is the code. This function automatically loads when the page gets loaded. I removed table-sorter to the table and tried this. It works. I have to get it to work with the table-sorter applied.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var row, len, results;
    row = 0;
    results = [];
    while (row < len) {
        if ($("#tab1 #example_"+row+"chkbx").is(":checked")) {
            $("#tab1 #example_" + row).css("background-color", "#c6b79f");
        }
        row++;
    }
    return results;
});
```

Comment: Can you not just edit the tablesorter css file?

Comment: Could you adjust your CSS to apply the style to sorted tables instead of modifying the JavaScript?

Comment: Please post your actual code. You neither initialize `len` nor use `results` in the posted snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options here,..

```
$("#tab1 #example_" + row).css("background-color", "#c6b79f");
```

- 1.) A selector with better specificity.
- 2.) Change the CSS file.
- 3.) Use !important.

The `3rd option` should work as a Quick fix but a bad practice. I prefer the `1st option`.

```
$("#tab1 #example_" + row).css("background-color", "#c6b79f    !important");
```

Comment: I am using table-sorter gem. I am not able to edit explicitly the css since it gets it from the gem.  I tried                              $("#tab1 #example_" + row).css("background-color", "#c6b79f    !important");  . Seems to be not supported for the mozilla browser

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [tablesorter gem](https://github.com/linjunpop/jquery-tablesorter-rails), I believe you might be using my fork of [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter).

I have [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/78/) with a parser that uses a checkbox to change the row color. It also updates the cache with the checkbox state so you can sort that column.

This parser won't work with the original version of tablesorter.

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'checkbox',
    is: function(s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        var $t = $(table), $c = $(cell), c,

        // resort the table after the checkbox status has changed
        resort = false;

        if (!$t.hasClass('hasCheckbox')) {
            $t
            .addClass('hasCheckbox')
            // make checkbox in header set all others
            .find('thead th:eq(' + cellIndex + ') input[type=checkbox]')
            .bind('change', function(){
                c = this.checked;
                $t.find('tbody tr td:nth-child(' + (cellIndex + 1) + ') input').each(function(){
                  this.checked = c;
                  $(this).trigger('change');
                });
            })
            .bind('mouseup', function(){
                return false;
            });
            $t.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
                $(this).find('td:eq(' + cellIndex + ')').find('input[type=checkbox]').bind('change', function(){
                    $t.trigger('updateCell', [$(this).closest('td')[0], resort]);
                });
            });
        }
        // return 1 for true, 2 for false, so true sorts before false
        c = ($c.find('input[type=checkbox]')[0].checked) ? 1 : 2;
        $c.closest('tr')[ c === 1 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]('checked');
        return c;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```